# How to dump command line instruction itself into output file?

Tags: windows, file, cmd, output, io-redirection

In the Windows command line, I want to dump the command line instruction directly into output file, aka
For instance, if I execute:

```
dir "C:\Program Files\*.exe" /B /S /O:GNE > "ExeList PgmFiles.txt"
```

I want into the output file "ExeList PgmFiles.txt" a first line with with the command line instructions itself(to keep track of what is actually executed), so in this example:

```
dir "C:\Program Files\*.exe" /B /S /O:GNE > "ExeList PgmFiles.txt"
```

then the file will get the actual execution output.
I tried:

```
dir "C:\Program Files\*.exe" /B /S /O:GNE 1 > "ExeList PgmFiles.txt" 0>&1
```

without success

Comment: Just nitpicking, but the Windows command-line really has nothing do do with DOS. DOS is an old OS you almost certainly isn't using today.

Comment: It's not `1 >` but `1>`...

Answer (score 2):

You can sort of get this result by assigning the command to a variable, then echoing the variable into a file, then executing the variable and appending the output into the same file.

The variable that contains all passed parameters is `%*`.
Let's put this into a batchfile "doit.bat":

```
@echo off
echo %*
%*
```

You can now prefix your command with "doit.bat" like this:

```
doit dir "C:\Program Files\*.exe" /B /S /O:GNE > "ExeList PgmFiles.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

The numbers in `1>` or `0>&1` have got the following meanings (consult the article [Redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) to learn more):

- handle `0` points to *STDIN*, that is the console or keyboard input
- handle `1` points to *STDOUT*, that is the console or display output
- handle `2` points to *STDERR*, that is the error display output

So you cannot redirect `0` (*STDIN*) to get the executed command line written to the redirection target.

One possible way was to simply [`echo`](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) the command line in advance, [escape](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html#escape) any special characters and redirect to the same target file, like this (note the escape sequence `^>`):

```cmd
echo dir "C:\Program Files\*.exe" /B /S /O:GNE ^> "ExeList PgmFiles.txt" > "ExeList PgmFiles.txt" 
dir "C:\Program Files\*.exe" /B /S /O:GNE >> "ExeList PgmFiles.txt"
```

But you may agree this is not quite elegant.

An alternative is to use the command echoes, which you can redirect together with the command output when you wrap around a [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) that iterates once only, like this:

```cmd
(for %Z in (.) do dir "C:\Program Files\*.exe" /B /S /O:GNE) > "ExeList PgmFiles.txt"
```

The command echoes must of course be enabled (by typing `@echo on`, for instance), so the hosting [`cmd.exe`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) instance must not have been started with the `/Q` option.

If you want to use the code in a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), make sure to change `%Z` to `%%Z`.